# Download PDF in browser with blob

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64, blob, arraybuffer

I can not quite wrap my head around on how to download a PDF from a google spreadsheet PDF Export Weblink. I generated a testing spreadsheet for this case.

I understand that I need to implement encodeURIComponent and/or "Buffer.from" to the blob but however I do it, it only downloads a broken PDF for me.

This is what I currently have in its rawest form. Thank you for your support!

**Node JS:**

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fLjKASR_g5wsvOjjJi6RclqMVd2o_1On-OfimXtId4E/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf&size=A4&fzr=true&gid=477517973&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false&portrait=true&fitw=true&fith=true&top_margin=0.20&bottom_margin=0.20&left_margin=0.20&right_margin=0.20";

let blob = await fetch(url).then(r => r.blob());

// then send blob variable to javascript
```

**Javascript:**

```
function downloadURI(name) {
        var uri = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + blob; 
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.download = name;
        link.href = uri;
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
        delete link;
      }
      downloadURI("test"+".pdf")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought that from `var uri = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + blob;` in your script, in this case, it is required to convert the downloaded data as the base64. Although I'm not sure about the relationship between the scripts between `Node JS:` and `Javascript:`, in your situation, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
let blob = await fetch(url).then(r => r.blob());
```

#### To:

```
let buf = await fetch(url).then((r) => r.arrayBuffer());
const data = Buffer.from(buf).toString("base64");
```

By this, you can use `data` as follows.

```
var uri = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + data;
```

#### Note:

- As the additional information, for example, if you want to download your Spreadsheet as a PDF file using only Javascript, you can also use the following script. But, in this case, the Spreadsheet is required to be publicly shared. Please be careful about this.

  ```
    async function downloadURI(name) {
      var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fLjKASR_g5wsvOjjJi6RclqMVd2o_1On-OfimXtId4E/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf&size=A4&fzr=true&gid=477517973&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false&portrait=true&fitw=true&fith=true&top_margin=0.20&bottom_margin=0.20&left_margin=0.20&right_margin=0.20";

      let blob = await fetch(url).then((r) => r.blob());
      var f = new FileReader();
      f.readAsDataURL(blob);
      f.onload = d => {
        var uri = d.target.result;
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.download = name;
        link.href = uri;
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
        delete link;
      }
    }
    downloadURI("test"+".pdf")
  ```

Comment: Hello Tanaike-San,
thank you so much for your valuable help. 
This helped me a lot. :-)
Wish you all the best!

Comment: @Kristian Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too!